# Best data structure for finding maximum in a 2d matrix with update queries

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have a 2d matrix of doubles. My task is to find the maximum element of the matrix at any point.

Queries will be of 2 types:

- Update query : In this query, 2n - 1 elements will be updated, i.e. all elements of row i and column i will be updated. (by updates I mean, change the element, it can be anything, increment or decrement)
- Maximum query : Return maximum element in the 2d array.

I came up with a solution by using binary heaps. My idea is to keep a maxheap of n^2 elements implemented using an array, and maintain another array of size n^2 to keep the indices of heap elements. So (i,j)th element in the matrix which is nothing but (i*n + j)th element in the flat array will store the index corresponding to its position in the heap.

So this way, 2n-1 updates will be handled in (2n-1)log(n^2) time. And maximum query can be answered in O(1) time.

I wasn't able to use STL implementation because I have to keep track of heap elements, i.e. upon update query I should know which heap elements are supposed to be updated. STL also doesn't support changing keys.

How do I improve the update query time? Is there some other data structure which can handle these operations faster?

Comment: is there any pattern for Update query? like increase element by a value v?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic no there is no such pattern. updates can be anything.

Comment: Two dimensional binary indexed tree can help.

Comment: btw, maybe you can use multiset and mimic the change key action by delete and then insert

Comment: benchmark your code.  There is no theoretical answer given the information provided.  Remember, algorithmic complexity != speed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a STL vector of indices `i*n+j`. Keep sorted this n^2 sized array using your own compare function. Sorting after update is n^2 O(log n^2). Querying the maximun is asking for the first element in the vector.

### Edit

If you're interested only in maximum value, you can keep its position (i,j) cached. When the matrix is updated it will need to be sorted again only if this cached position change.

Comment: Can you explain how sorting after update is O(log(n^2))?

Comment: @user3286661 Sorry, the right answer is `O(n^2 log(n^2)))` .I correct my answer. Anyhow, I doubt it can be done in less complexity.